# Generate Kotlin classes from wsdl file using maven

Tags: kotlin, wsdl, maven-plugin

I would like to generate Kotlin classes from a given wsdl file. How can I do this using a maven plugin like jaxb2-maven-plugin or cxf-codegen-plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by reading their respective documentation. What have you tried and has not worked?

Comment: Hi Alex, I have looked at the  respective documentation and there is nothing there about generating kotlin classes from a SOAP Webservice wsdl file. If you have found something, can you pls provide a link. 

My solution for now is generating Java classes and using them in my kotlin code. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-soap-web-service